# Move a menu via css?

Tags: css, wordpress

My new Responsive `Wordpress` theme, is fine on all browser and mobile.

But in Samsung and Motorola the menu is away to the top right, not in its place.

and in Amazon Kindle it shows half background image.

**Screenshot on Samsung Galaxy S2:**

[image]

---

**Screenshot on Kindle Fire:**

[image]

How can i fix this problem? I have searched a lot but can not find any solution.

Comment: Probably far better if you supplied some HTML + CSS!

Comment: here is theme URI: http://www.moonthemes.com/fitotheme

Answer (score 0):

after inspecting your theme I came to following conclusion may be helpful to you
if you look closer

.slogan-main class has float: left property. so element next to it that is wrapper of navigation might not be clearing float.

so I guess you need to use clear : both property on parent of navigation element or any other method by means of which you can clear float

as I don't have devices I haven't got chance to test this, so I am not sure whether this is correct